# Semantic versioning and backward compatibility

Tags: typescript, semantic-versioning

I have a function that is a part of a public API that returns some object. Without strict check option it can also return `undefined`. Now, I want to turn on strict checks in my project, and because this function actually have flow that can return an `undefined` typescript now demands to add `|undefined` to the return type. Does this constitute patch version update, minor, or major?

The thing is that if some application consumed the library with strict check enabled, with the new version it is possible that it will no longer compile. So, in that regard it is no longer backward compatible. On the other hand, the current version returns `undefined` in some cases, so the new version actually brings no API changes.

So I can see that I could increase all three versions:

1. Major – because with this version the client code no longer compiles
2. Minor – because this is a observable change to the API but one that is backward compatible
3. Patch – because there is in fact no change to the behaviour

Here is a simplified code change between versions:

Old version (strict check disabled):

```
function foo(val: number): Object {
    if (val < 0) {
        return;
    }
    return { val };
}
```

New version (strict check enabled):

```
function foo(val: number): Object|undefined {
    if (val < 0) {
        return;
    }
    return { val };
}
```

Comment: Well for me it seems not a patch change, as if anyone is using ^3.1.1 for version range it would break their code. I think the correct would be to release minor or major. For me, major is breaking change which seems not the case here.

Comment: That was also my intuition, and so I went with minor.

Comment: If it breaks the build, it's a breaking change and requires a major version bump.